# フォームのラベルをinputタグの上に表示させるアニメーションを作りたいですがラベルの非表示の切り替え方がわかりません

Tags: html, css, jquery

フォームのラベルをフォーカスされたときにinputタグの上に表示させるアニメーションを作りたいですがラベルの非表示の切り替え方がわかりません

今のソースコードはこのようになってますが問題があります
１つはフォーカスしていないときでもラベルが非表示になっていないことです。どのようにすればうまく実装できるのかわかりませんでした
２つはラベルが２つありますが、２つとも同じ位置に行ってしまうことです。これもどうやって制御して位置を対応させればいいのかがわかりませんでした

jqueryを使っていますがJavascriptやCSSのみの方法でも構いませんのでご回答お願い致します。

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-group input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).siblings('label').addClass('active');
  });

  $('.form-group input').on('blur', function() {
    if (!$(this).val() && !$(this).attr('required')) {
      $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-group input {
  position: relative;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 120%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.9s ease-out all;
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-group input:focus+label,
.form-group input:valid+label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="username" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="username">ユーザー名</label>
      </div> <br> <br> <br>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="email">メールアドレス</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> １つはフォーカスしていないときでもラベルが非表示になっていないことです。

JavaScript コードで `<label>` に `active` クラスを付け外ししているので、「`.active` があるときは表示、ないときは非表示」というスタイルを足しましょう。

> ２つはラベルが２つありますが、２つとも同じ位置に行ってしまうことです。

現在のコードではどちらの `<label>` も `position: absolute` で `top: 0` です。この座標の原点は `<body>` になりますから、同じ位置に表示されます。
別の原点にするには、たとえば `col` クラスに `position: relative` などを付ければよいでしょう。

```js
// 変更なし
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-group input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).siblings('label').addClass('active');
  });

  $('.form-group input').on('blur', function() {
    if (!$(this).val() && !$(this).attr('required')) {
      $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-group input {
  position: relative;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100vh;  /* 2 */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.9s ease-out all;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;  /* 1 */
}

.form-group input:focus+label.active,
.form-group input:valid+label.active {  /* 1 */
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #555;
  visibility: visible;  /* 1 */
}

/* 2 */
.form-group .col {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="username" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="username">ユーザー名</label>
      </div> <br> <br> <br>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="email">メールアドレス</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```